# ¿Cómo hacer eventos en tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Como puedo hacer para que en mi "calculadora" cuando le presione la tecla "enter" del teclado, me de inmediatamente la respuesta, sin que yo este moviendo el mouse para precionar el botón igual.

Adjunto la forma en la que estoy llevando el boton_igual para que me arroje la operación

```
boton_igual = Button(ventana, text="=", width=5, height=2, command=lambda: operaciones())
boton_igual.grid(row=5, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)
ventana.mainloop()
```

Gracias por su atención

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asumiendo que tu variable `ventana` es donde has hecho `Tk()`, puedes hacer esto:

```
ventana.bind('<Return>', lambda e: operaciones())
ventana.bind('<KP_Enter>', lambda e: operaciones())
```

Hay dos cosas importantes:

- El método [`bind()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-binding-function-in-tkinter/) (ahí te dejo varios ejemplos) permite asignar eventos a los objetos de tkinter, en este caso nos interesa asignárselo a la ventana para que esta pueda detectar los eventos da igual donde esté el foco.
- La lambda: la lambda debe recibir un evento, así que se declara (en la variable `e` estará el evento) y lo que hace es llamar a tu método `operaciones()` que supongo que es lo que te interesa. Lo he bindeado a dos teclas diferentes, uno es el enter del teclado y el otro el enter del teclado numérico.

Espero que te sirva, ante cualquier duda aquí estamos.

Comment: Gracias @Benito-B por tu gran aporte, me sirvió mucho la respuesta y la explicación